# Conditions under which $az+b\overline{z}+c=0$ in one complex unknown has one solution

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

> Find the conditions under which the equation $a z + b \overline{z} + c = 0$ in one complex unknown has exactly one solution, and compute that solution.

In the following solution that I found to this problem, I'm unsure how they rewrote $a(x+iy)+b(x-iy)+c=0$ as equations $(1.6a)$ and $(1.6b)$.  Why do we get two equations?  And I'm just starting to read Ahlfors "Complex Analysis" and this is a question early in the text.

Thanks

> Let $z = x + iy$.
>   Then $az + b\overline{z} + c = a(x+iy) + b(x-iy) + c = 0$.
>   \begin{align}
>   (a+b)x + c &= 0 \tag{1.6a} \\
>       (a-b)y &= 0 \tag{1.6b}
> \end{align}
>   Lets consider equation $(1.6b)$.
>   We either have that $a = b$ or $y = 0$.
>   If $a = b$ then WLOG equation (1.6a) can be written as
>   $$
>   x = \frac{-c}{2a}
> $$
>   and $y \in \mathbb{R}$.
>   For fixed $a,b,c$, we have infinitely many solutions when $a = b$ since $z = -c/(2a) + iy$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$. […]
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB5WU.png).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the basic fact about complex numbers. For complex numbers $u,v$:

$$ u = v \qquad \text{if and only if} \qquad
\mathrm{Re}(u) = \mathrm{Re}(v) \quad \text{and} \quad
\mathrm{Im}(u) = \mathrm{Im}(v) $$

Equations 1.6a and 1.6b are just the real and imaginary parts of the original equation to solve (assuming $a,b,c,x,y$ are all real numbers), and so together they are equivalent to the original equation.